# Is there a way to solve error in Router Path, RouterV6 React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Is there a way to solve this?
I am having an error `Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`
I have also tried to change the position of the routers but haven't managed to solve the problem

Here is my App.js - I have installed react-router-dom

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import About from "./components/about/About";
import Contact from "./components/contact/Contact";
import Intro from "./components/intro/Intro";
import ProductList from "./components/productList/ProductList";
import Devs from "./components/developers/Devs";

import Toggle from "./components/toggle/Toggle";
import { ThemeContext } from "./context";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const darkMode = theme.state.darkMode;
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundColor: darkMode ? "#222" : "white",
        color: darkMode && "white",
      }}
    >
        <Intro />
        <About />
        <ProductList />
        <Contact />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/devs' element={<Devs />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Devs.jsx - Here is the jsx file that I would like to navigate

```
import "./devs.css";
const Devs = () => {
  return (
    <div className="d">
        Devs
    </div>
  );
};

export default Devs;
```

Comment: You imported a `BrowserRouter` but where are you rendering it? The `Routes` component uses `useRoutes` and the error is saying there is no routing context above it in the ReactTree.

Answer (score 0):

Routes should be wrapped inside the `BrowserRouter`. You can also create a `routes.js` file that handles all your `routes` for a much cleaner code.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Component1 />} />
        <Route path="/component2" element={<Component2 />} />
        <Route path="/component3" element={<Component3 />} />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```